# Switch Router with Navbar

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I would like a navbar on top of every page except the "introduction" page. Is this the right way to do it? Is there a cleaner way to do it?

```
<BrowserRouter>
    <div>
        <Switch>
            <Route exact path = "/" component = {Introduction} />
            <div>
                <Navbar/>
                <PrivateRoute path = "/main" component = {main} />)
                <PrivateRoute path = "/other" component = {other} />)
            </div>
        </Switch>
    </div>
</BrowserRouter>
```

Comment: Hi Punisher, any luck on implementing this? Let me know if you need any help!

Answer (score 1):

You can accomplish that by doing something like this:

```
class App extends React.Component{
    render(){
        const DefaultRoutes = () => {
            return(
                <div>
                    <Navbar/>
                    <Switch>
                        <PrivateRoute path = "/main" component = {main} />)
                        <PrivateRoute path = "/other" component = {other} />)
                    </Switch>                                                                                                           
                </div>
            )
        }

        return(
            <BrowserRouter>
                <div>
                    <Switch>
                        <Route exact path = "/" component = {Introduction} />
                        <Route component={DefaultRoutes}/>
                    </Switch>
                </div>
            </BrowserRouter>
        )
    }
}

export default App
```

Define a DefaultRoutes function that includes all the Routes which would have the Navbar. Then use that function as the component for a Route in your BrowserRouter.
Everything else that does not need a Navbar can be defined in its own Route like Introduction